# Handling events in a Task; Handling Navigated event from WebBrowser in Task?

Tags: c#

I am rewriting some code that uses a `WebBrowser` object to determine when a server is ready to have a file downloaded. Overall the behavior is this, first a file is uploaded to the server, once it is uploaded the server then gets to work, as it is doing work it redirects users connected to a specific page it serves to various URLs until it is done, once it is done then the file is ready to be downloaded.

I would like to have all of this behavior in a single function call, basically `GetFileFromServer()`. Once this call returns then the file is at a specified file path.

The issue is when using the `WebBrowser` I have to handle the `Navigated` event to determine when the file is ready to be downloaded, this takes the program flow away from the `GetFileFromServer` function. I could just have a small while loop

```
while(fileNotDownloaded)
    Thread.Sleep(500);
```

But I would like to use a `Task` instead so that the function looks something like

```
public void GetFileFromServer()
{
    UploadFile();   // Blocks until file is uploaded
    DownloadFile(); // Blocks until file is downloaded
}
```

I have implemented `UploadFile` but, again, am having issues with `DownnloadFile`. Basically I would like my function too look like so

```
private void DownloadFile()
{
    var DoWebDriverTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Boolean fileReady = false;
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Url = new Uri(MySpecificIP);
        webBrowser.Navigated += WebBrowserNavigated;

        // Sit and Spin until the specific URL is navigated to
        while(!fileReady)
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { Task.Delay(500) });

        DownloadFile();

        private void WebBrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Contains("mySpecificURLString"))
                fileReady = true;
        }
    }, CancelWaitForDownloadTaskToken);
    Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { WebDriverTask });
}
```

But this obviously is not proper code. I also understand this is the same solution I offer above but just moved into a `Task`, but it does give me the behavior I want out of `GetFileFromServer`. Note, none of this is going on in the UI thread as is, so again, the solution I offer above is viable... But using a `Task` I would have the ability to cancel waiting on the download if the user wishes to.

So is there a way to handle the event `Navigated` within the `Task` as I "described" in the code above?

Comment: I think that you should use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Or you can convert `WebBrowserNavigated` to a lambda expression. But using a `TaskCompletionSource` is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can handle the event in the same scope of the method:

```
webBrowser.Navigated += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Contains("mySpecificURLString"))
        fileReady = true;
};
```

However, looping and waiting is not a very good idea, here is a better alternative:

```
private Task WaitBeforeDownloadFile(WebBrowser webBrowser)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler web_browser_on_navigated = null;

    web_browser_on_navigated = (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Contains("mySpecificURLString"))
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            webBrowser.Navigated -= web_browser_on_navigated;
        }
    };

    webBrowser.Navigated += web_browser_on_navigated;

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This method creates a `Task` that completes when the `Navigated` event is raised and the condition you specified is met.

Here is how you would use it:

```
private void DownloadFile()
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.Url = new Uri(MySpecificIP);

    //Initiate whatever here before waiting for the Navigated event

    WaitBeforeDownloadFile(webBrowser).Wait();

    //Continue here
}
```

Which again is not a very good thing to do. However, since you want a synchronous behavior, then you have to do it like this.

A better alternative that requires a lot of changes to how you do things is to do things asynchronously which requires a good amount of learning to do. Here is an example:

```
public async Task GetFileFromServer()
{
    await UploadFile();
    await DownloadFile();
}

public async Task UploadFile()
{
    ...
}

public async Task DownloadFile()
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser.Url = new Uri(MySpecificIP);

    //Initiate whatever here before waiting for the Navigated event

    await WaitBeforeDownloadFile(webBrowser);

    //Continue here
}
```